# How do I use regex in sheets to number (in cell) everything new line that starts with Letters?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet, transpose, textjoin

My goal is to get something like this [goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRAbs.png). For every new line after the 1st one if it doesn't start with a ">" I want it to be numbered (starting from nr. 1 on), as for the lines that start with ">" - to just return those without numbering them. I've tried to insert strings with the numbers [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvvmG.png), the problem is I don't know how many lines I might have that don't start with ">" and if these are intercalated with the other ones - so I can't really "hardcode" the string into the formula, as I did. Any solutions? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(""&
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)), "^>.*"), 
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)), TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10))))<=SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)))))*NOT(REGEXMATCH(
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)), "^>.+")))), TRANSPOSE(SIGN(NOT(REGEXMATCH(
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)), "^>.+"))))))&". "&
 SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)))))
```

[image]

Comment: that seems to work indeed, would you care to break it down for me a little bit?

Comment: @DeboraS. sure, see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GAsrnCq9L6Aentbpurl-c9NuSIpiIjiyTYHjox_HA64/edit#gid=0

Comment: That's really helpful! But what if I wanted it to start the numbering (sequence) from the 2nd line on (so: abc (\n); 1. xxx; etc.) , as I was able to do in my formula. I can't quite get how to do that with yours.

Comment: @DeboraS. you can do it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3fQj.png